# LINQ result to dataset in C#: Unable to cast AnonymousType to DataSet

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I want to fetch my result and convert it to `Dataset`. My code is :

```
var res = 
    from i in dbconnect.tblManageDates
    where i.internationalCode == _international
    select new
    {
        i.companyId,
        i.endDate,
        i.startDate,
        i.dateId
    };

_result = (DataSet)res;
```

When I fetch it to `Dataset` I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Int32]]'
>   to type 'System.Data.DataSet'.

Comment: What is the purpose of it being a `Dataset` as the end result? The query would bind directly to several controls; `DataGridView`, `DataGrid`, `ListView`, etc...(depending on Platform).

Comment: _result is a Dataset ,i want to return it as a Datasource for my Datagridview

Comment: The `DataSource` property does not accept a `DataSet` as a binding, it will use a `DataTable`, `List<T>`, `IEnumberable<T>`, etc... Did you try to bind your query to the DGV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use such extension:

```
public static class Extesions
{
    public static DataSet ToDataSet<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        Type elementType = typeof(T);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        ds.Tables.Add(t);

        //add a column to table for each public property on T
        foreach (var propInfo in elementType.GetProperties())
        {
            Type ColType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propInfo.PropertyType) ?? propInfo.PropertyType;

            t.Columns.Add(propInfo.Name, ColType);
        }

        //go through each property on T and add each value to the table
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            DataRow row = t.NewRow();

            foreach (var propInfo in elementType.GetProperties())
            {
                row[propInfo.Name] = propInfo.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
            }

            t.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return ds;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int DateId { get; set; }
}

// ...

List<Entity> res = dbconnect.tblManageDates.Where(i => i.internationalCode == _international).Select(i => new Entity
{
    CompanyId = i.companyId,
    EndDate = i.endDate,
    StartDate = i.startDate,
    DateId = i.dateId
}).ToList();

DataSet dataSet = res.ToDataSet();
```